# Using emojis in shiny selectInput widget dropdown options

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny selectInput widget used to select climatic conditions as follows

```
selectInput("selectedconditions", "Select Climatic Conditions :",
                c("Temperature" = "temp",
                  "Relative Humidity" = "rh",
                  "Barometric Pressure" = "pressure",
                  "Wind Speed" = "wspeed"), multiple = TRUE)
```

I also want to include emojis preceding the options displayed in the dropdown menu. I'd like to use [Hadley Wickams emo package](https://github.com/hadley/emo) for this.

I tried doing `paste0(emo::ji("sun"),"Temperature")` in trying to generate the dropdown text but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package as is in a {shiny} context. Your problem arises, because you try to use `paste` inside `c()` when defining the name argument. If you use `setNames` instead it will work:

```
library(shiny)
library(emo)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    selectInput("selectedconditions",
                paste0("Select Climatic Conditions", emo::ji("sun")), #
                setNames(c("temp", "rh", "pressure", "wspeed"),
                          c(paste0("Temperature", emo::ji("sun")), "Relative Humidity",
                          "Barometric Pressure", "Wind Speed")),
    multiple = TRUE)),

  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
  }
)
```